# How to attach files to Visual Studio Test with Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: rest, automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**TL;DR:** How do I relate a release to the tests visible in the Tests tab via the API?

I am running a Release Pipeline which executes tests against the website being deployed. The tests generate files (within my test code) and I want to use the DevOps REST API to attach those files to the Test report associated with the Release.

Note: I am running these tests as smoke tests after release as part of the release pipeline so that I can test the deployed website. This would not be possible as part of the build pipeline.

I can [get the release information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1), but I'm having trouble identifying how to find the related test(s) and attach a file.

[image]

**Additional:** The link in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041873/71376) appears to have been changed and no longer points to the intended page, but now points to the overall documentation for the REST API.

Currently, I believe the process should be:

- Get release details
- Get test run id
- Get test case result id
- Create test result attachment

The primary problem is getting the `test run id` and `test case result id` from the release information.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm a bit late with this, but still.

You are right about the process. Getting **Test run ID** is possible via accessing logs of corresponding task inside the release. Here's the needed endpoint:

```
 https://{organizationName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseID}/environments/{stageID}/deployPhases/{deployPhaseID}/tasks/{taskId}/logs
```

Please note that test run ID and test IDs will only be available **after the test run task is finished**.

I'd recommend getting release ID, stage ID and deployment phase ID directly from the release by accessing default variables provided by azure devops (e.g. **$(Release.ReleaseId)**, other ones are easily googled) rather than fetching via API and matching by name, cause it takes time and does not return all releases, only 100 first or smth like that.

After this, you need to get **TaskID**. I found it possible and applicable looking for that by Task Name. Just fetch the release by it's ID via API and look for task which matches needed name using this endpoint:

```
https://{organizationName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.0
```

Going through all the deploySteps, deployPhases, deployJobs to get the task name is a bit cumbersome, but possible (I used LINQ).

After getting these 4 base IDs, you are now able to get logs of the Run tests task. In received log I have used a regex to extract test run ID. Then, having test run ID, you can grab the list of test run results:

```
https://{organizationName}.visualstudio.com/{projectName}/_apis/test/runs/{testRunId}/results
```

To attach some files to a test, you will need this test's AzDo ID. How can you get it? Well, I can think of mapping the tests by their names (you will need to store a list of those beforehand) and then looping through fetched test results and the stored list. After a match is found, get the respective id, and attach anything you want:

```
https://{organizationName}.visualstudio.com/{projectName}/_apistest/Runs/{testRunId}/Results/{testId}/attachments?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```